Kivy app automaticly crashing on android after presplash is loaded
So this is my first Kivy app, I had this Idea to make a script which would search up song details from spotify then download it from youtube as an audio,
until now working perfectly on my windows so I decided to try to make it work on my android.
I've run the buildozer build, specified the requirements and permissions everything worked smoothly, but after installing the apk, it showed me the logo I chose as presplash and then directly automaticly crashed, I tried again and it still has this behaviour.
I susspect the issue I am facing is because of using multiple modules and not reffering to them in the requirements.
for instance I have two classes each in a seprate module, and a main.py
#main.py
import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from musicdownloader import MusicDownloader
from youtube import YoutubeDownloader

class DownloaderApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Create a BoxLayout
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=10, spacing=10)
        
        # YouTube Downloader Section
        self.layout.add_widget(Label(text="YouTube Video URL:"))
        self.youtube_url_input = TextInput(hint_text="Enter YouTube URL")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.youtube_url_input)

        youtube_download_btn = Button(text="Download YouTube Video")
        youtube_download_btn.bind(on_press=self.download_youtube_video)
        self.layout.add_widget(youtube_download_btn)

        # Spotify Downloader Section
        self.layout.add_widget(Label(text="Spotify Track URL or ID:"))
        self.spotify_input = TextInput(hint_text="Enter Spotify URL or ID")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.spotify_input)

        spotify_download_btn = Button(text="Download Spotify Song")
        spotify_download_btn.bind(on_press=self.download_spotify_song)
        self.layout.add_widget(spotify_download_btn)

        return self.layout

    def get_save_path(self):
        """
        Determines the save path based on the platform.
        On Android: Uses the app's storage directory.
        On other platforms: Uses the "Downloads" directory.
        """
        if os.name == "posix":  # Likely Android
            save_path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download"  # Typical Android download path
        else:  # Likely Windows or Linux
            save_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "videos")

        os.makedirs(save_path, exist_ok=True)
        return save_path

    def download_youtube_video(self, instance):
        url = self.youtube_url_input.text
        if not url:
            self.show_popup("Error", "Please enter a YouTube URL.")
            return

        save_path = self.get_save_path()
        try:
            # Use YoutubeDownloader class to download video
            YoutubeDownloader.download_video(url, save_path)
            self.show_popup("Success", "YouTube video downloaded successfully!")
        except Exception as e:
            self.show_popup("Error", f"Failed to download YouTube video: {e}")

    def download_spotify_song(self, instance):
        spotify_input = self.spotify_input.text
        if not spotify_input:
            self.show_popup("Error", "Please enter a Spotify URL or ID.")
            return

        save_path = self.get_save_path()
        try:
            # Use MusicDownloader class to search and download song
            music_downloader = MusicDownloader()
            music_downloader.search_song_on_spotify_and_youtube(spotify_input)
            self.show_popup("Success", "Spotify song downloaded successfully!")
        except Exception as e:
            self.show_popup("Error", f"Failed to download Spotify song: {e}")

    def show_popup(self, title, message):
        content = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=10)
        content.add_widget(Label(text=message))
        close_btn = Button(text="Close")
        content.add_widget(close_btn)

        popup = Popup(title=title, content=content, size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 200))
        close_btn.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)
        popup.open()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DownloaderApp().run()

#youtube.py

from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
import os

class YoutubeDownloader():
    
    @staticmethod
    def download_video(url, save_path='videos'):
        try:
            # Ensure the 'videos' folder exists (default to 'videos' if no path is provided)
            if not os.path.exists(save_path):
                os.makedirs(save_path)
            
            # Configure yt-dlp options
            ydl_opts = {
                'format' : 'best[ext=mp4]',  # Best quality mp4 format
                'outtmpl' : os.path.join(save_path, '%(title)s.%(ext)s'),  # Save path with video title
            }
            
            with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                ydl.download([url])
            print("Video downloaded successfully")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            
    @staticmethod
    def download_audio(url, save_path='music', preferred_codec="mp3", preferred_quality="320"):
        try:
            # Ensure the save_path exists (default to 'music' if no path is provided)
            if not os.path.exists(save_path):
                os.makedirs(save_path)

            # Configure yt-dlp options for high-quality audio
            ydl_opts = {
                'format': 'bestaudio/best',  # Get the best audio format available
                'postprocessors': [{
                    'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                    'preferredcodec': preferred_codec,  # Codec: mp3, wav, flac, etc.
                    'preferredquality': preferred_quality,  # Quality: 128, 192, 320 kbps
                }],
                'outtmpl': os.path.join(save_path, '%(title)s.%(ext)s'),  # Save with audio title
            }

            # Download the audio
            with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                ydl.download([url])
            print(f"Audio downloaded successfully in {preferred_codec} format at {preferred_quality} kbps.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    @staticmethod
    def download_playlist(url, save_path='videos'):
        try:
            # Ensure the save_path exists
            if not os.path.exists(save_path):
                os.makedirs(save_path)
            
            # Configure yt-dlp options for downloading a playlist
            ydl_opts = {
                'format': 'best[ext=mp4]',  # Best quality mp4 format
                'outtmpl': os.path.join(save_path, '%(playlist)s', '%(title)s.%(ext)s'),  # Save playlist in a folder
                'noplaylist': False,  # Allow downloading the entire playlist
                'ignoreerrors': True,  # Ignore errors and continue downloading
            }
            
            with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                ydl.download([url])
            print("Playlist downloaded successfully")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while downloading the playlist: {e}")

#musicdownloader.py
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
import os
import re
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import logging

# Load environment variables from .env
load_dotenv()

class MusicDownloader:
    
    def __init__(self):
        # Get Spotify credentials from environment variables
        self.spotify_client_id = os.getenv("SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID")
        self.spotify_client_secret = os.getenv("SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET")
        self.spotify = self.authenticate_spotify()

    def authenticate_spotify(self):
        """
        Authenticates with Spotify API using Client Credentials Flow.
        """
        client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(
            client_id=self.spotify_client_id, 
            client_secret=self.spotify_client_secret
        )
        return spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

    def extract_track_id(self, spotify_input):
        """
        Extracts the track ID from a Spotify URL or validates if it's already an ID.
        """
        if "open.spotify.com" in spotify_input:
            match = re.search(r"track/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)", spotify_input)
            if match:
                return match.group(1)
            else:
                raise ValueError("Invalid Spotify URL.")
        return spotify_input  # Assume input is a valid track ID if it's not a URL

    def get_song_details(self, track_input):
        """
        Retrieves song details from Spotify using the song's Spotify track ID or URL.
        """
        try:
            track_id = self.extract_track_id(track_input)
            track = self.spotify.track(track_id)
            song_details = {
                'name': track['name'],
                'artist': track['artists'][0]['name'],
                'album': track['album']['name'],
            }
            return song_details
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while retrieving song details: {e}")
            return None

    def search_youtube(self, song_details):
        """
        Searches YouTube for the song based on the song details (name + artist).
        Downloads the audio as MP3 into a 'music' folder.
        """
        try:
            # Search query
            search_query = f"{song_details['name']} {song_details['artist']} "
            print(f"Searching for: {search_query}")
            
            # Set up the music folder path
            music_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'music')
            
            # Ensure the 'music' folder exists
            if not os.path.exists(music_folder):
                os.makedirs(music_folder)
            
            # Set up logging
            logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
            logger = logging.getLogger()

            # yt-dlp options
            ydl_opts = {
                'quiet': False,  # Enable verbose logging to track what's happening
                'format': 'bestaudio/best',  # Download the best available audio
                'noplaylist': True,  # Avoid playlist results
                'extractaudio': True,  # Extract audio only (not video)
                'audioquality': 1,  # Highest audio quality
                'outtmpl': os.path.join(music_folder, '%(title)s.%(ext)s'),  # Save to 'music' folder
                'postprocessors': [{
                    'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',  # Use FFmpeg to extract and convert audio
                    'preferredcodec': 'mp3',  # Convert to MP3
                    'preferredquality': '192',  # Set bitrate to 192kbps
                }],
                'logger': logger  # Add logger to yt-dlp options
            }

            # Perform download
            with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                ydl.download([f"ytsearch:{search_query}"])

            print(f"Search complete. Audio downloaded and converted to MP3 successfully.")
        
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while searching on YouTube: {e}")

    def search_song_on_spotify_and_youtube(self, track_input):
        """
        Searches for a song on Spotify (via URL or ID) and then finds it on YouTube.
        """
        song_details = self.get_song_details(track_input)
        if song_details:
            print(f"Song details retrieved: {song_details}")
            self.search_youtube(song_details)
        else:
            print("Failed to retrieve song details.")


Try connecting your android to your PC and then run buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt. You should be able to see crash information in the file my_log.txt. See the documentation.
